# Mootools function callback

Tags: javascript, mootools

How can I make sure that the thankyou fades in only after the newsletter fades out?

```
overlay_newsletter.fade('out');
thankYou.setStyle('display', 'block').fade('in');
```

The following doesn't seem to work

```
 overlay_newsletter.fade('out' function(){
   thankYou.setStyle('display', 'block').fade('in');
 });
```

Comment: Alex, was my answer useful?

Comment: Hi there, I am sorry not quite, I ended up doing sth like this, but I am trying to find a better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/KjDZn/, I am not confident with Mootools as much as I am with jQuery...

Comment: Ok, but if you wan't to fire the fade in after the fade out is done, my code works. Did you try it? I will update with the three steps.

Comment: I will give it a go a compare the two, thanks for your help...

Comment: Ok, let me know if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your markup looks like so I made my own demo ([**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/823D7/)) that runs on mouseover.

```
var afterfadeout = function () {
    alert('complete');
    thankYou.setStyle('display', 'block').fade('in');
};
overlay_newsletter.set('tween', {
    onComplete: afterfadeout
});
```